# Fill in the blank: "____ of mythology"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I just posted a [question](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/q/2222/967) over in the Mythology SE and used this sentence:

> I'm tagging Greek and Roman mythology, but open to other mythologies as well.

I wanted to say:

> I'm tagging Greek and Roman mythology, but open to **other ____ of mythology** as well.

I couldn't think of the proper word to go in the blank. *'Branches'* didn't seem to fit because the different world mythologies don't really branch from each other. *'Types'* didn't feel right either--there really aren't types of mythology. Same problem with *'varieties'* and *'variations'*.

What word would fit in that blank?

Comment: The sentence that you actually used ("... other mythologies ...") sounds perfectly fine to me. Why do you want to change it? (In fact, you can shorten it to "... others as well.").

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Mythology is associated with a culture, religion, geographic region, etc. [Merriam-Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/culture) sense 5b of **culture** is

> the customary beliefs, social forms, and material traits of a racial, religious, or social group; also :  the characteristic features of everyday existence (as diversions or a way of life) shared by people in a place or time.

So you could say

> ... but open to the mythology of different cultures as well.

Comment: I would say "...but open to the *mythologies* of different cultures as well" (plural); but otherwise, great answer!

Comment: @Quuxplusone, I was thinking about whether to use *mythology* or *mythologies,* but settled on the singular, since I would use the singular for poetry, literature, etc.

Comment: In all those cases (e.g. "the literatures of different cultures"), to me, the plural connotes exactness but maybe pedantry, whereas the singular runs the risk of casually implying that there's only one "literature of different cultures" (as opposed to, you know, *normal* literature). As a product of U.S. high schools, I've certainly been exposed to "the literature of different cultures" in that sense — there's the English literary tradition and then there's the literary tradition of Chinua Achebe and Gabriel García Márquez. ;) Using the plural makes it sound more, y'know, *plural*.

Answer (score 23):

I don't see any problem with the way you constructed your sentence, but if you want a different term you might try [**systems**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/system) of mythology.

This term appears to be used in the way you want:

> We would therefore invite the attention of the reader to a brief
>   comparison between the Norse and Greek **systems of mythology**. ([C.S.
>   Griggs, *Norse Mythology*, 1884](https://books.google.com/books?id=IWYuAAAAYAAJ&lpg=PA51&ots=VV-cz1uUIJ&dq=%22systems%20of%20mythology%22&pg=PA52#v=onepage&q=%22systems%20of%20mythology%22&f=false))
>
> The similarities between the various **systems of mythology** could be
>   explained, for Schelling, by reference to the schemata of his own
>   Potenzenlehre, and not by empirical research into historical
>   influences. ([Robert Gascoigne, *Religion, Rationality and Community*,
>   2012](https://books.google.com/books?id=5XVyBgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA207&ots=cEUM8o8QCj&dq=%22systems%20of%20mythology%22&pg=PA208#v=onepage&q=%22systems%20of%20mythology%22&f=false))
>
> Analyze and account for the relationships that obtain between
>   mythology, religion, and philosophy in various **systems of mythology**,
>   as well as mythology’s expressions in art, literature, and society.
>   ([Learning objective in syllabus for a 2016 World Mythology university
>   course](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.csus.edu/hum/department%2520contact/warnes.151sp16.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwij09LK3qLRAhWD64MKHbgHAY44ChAWCFEwDw&usg=AFQjCNGslDkHoj-A8cfcIFjA25TIfuLEww&sig2=MVo4PzHV-Bp8CHB1WA4VHg)—link is a PDF download)

Comment: This fit my exact wording the best, but Katherine's answer better fit my intent. Have an upvote!

Answer (score 4):

How about "Pantheons"?

From the Oxford dictionary: "All the gods of a people or religion collectively:
‘the deities of the Hindu pantheon’"

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pantheon

Comment: That's just the gods, though. It wouldn't necessarily include humans or non-human, non-deific (?) characters.

Comment: Ah yeah I see what you're saying... Heh, the word has been somewhat hijacked by Tolkien nerds, but Legendarium is probably closer to what you're thinking then.

Answer (score 3):

Mythos would certainly work.

> I'm tagging Greek and Roman mythology, but open to other *mythoi* as well.

Comment: That's just a synonym for 'mythologies', so this is no better than the first sentence in the question.

Comment: But *mythoi* sounds cooler and is also used more

Comment: @bleh [Definitely not used more](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mythologies%2Cmythoi&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cmythologies%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmythologies%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMythologies%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cmythoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmythoi%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMythoi%3B%2Cc0)...

Comment: Never mind then

Answer (score 3):

## Bodies

As in:

> I'm tagging Greek and Roman mythology, but open to other *bodies* of mythology as well.

This is using what Merriam-Webster gives as [definition 3c](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/body):

> 3c:  aggregate, quantity <a *body* of evidence>

and a [Google search for the phrase](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%22bodies+of+mythology%22) returns many results, as does one for "[bodies of myth](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%22bodies+of+myth%22)". (Also see particularly Google Books searches [1](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bodies%20of%20mythology%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), [2](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22bodies%20of%20myth%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en).

"Systems", as suggested in another answer, is also good (and reasonably common), but it implies a, well, *systematicness* that not all mythologies have. Many are collections of stories and tales with not much internal coherence (and are just fine with that). I think "body" better applies.

Answer (score 2):

In the same strain as *culture* of mythology, I believe that *tradition* would work better, as it can also highlight differences between regional worship of the same faith.

> 1 a : an inherited, established, or customary pattern of thought, action, or behavior (such as a religious practice or a social custom)

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tradition

For example

> open to other traditions of mythology as well.

or

> open to other mythological traditions as well.

Comment: I like it.  Now you are supposed to provide a definition and a link to a definition.  Then copy the OP's example sentence and show how your word fits in.  Let me know with a message containing @aparente001 if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Milieu:  the physical or social setting in which something occurs or develops

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/milieu

Comment: But wouldn't that be more specifically for the originating culture rather than the mythology itself? "I'm ...open to other **milieus** of mythology" is awkward but correct?

Comment: You might be right, milieu wo uld refer to other cultures... you would be saying 'I'm open to other cultural standards of mythology.' Which is what I thought you were going for. Maybe you are looking for 'genre?'

Comment: But would Greek/Egyptian/Ainu be considered genres?

Comment: No I guess not. Context? "I'm open to other contexts....l"

Answer (score 0):

**Instances** would fit the bill:

[Instance:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/instance)

> 1. a case or occurrence of anything   - *dictionary.com*

Answer (score 0):

If we consider mythology as a *genre*, then we are talking of Greek, Roman and other ***subgenres*** of mythology.

> I'm tagging Greek and Roman mythology, but open to other
>   ***subgenres*** of mythology as well.

ODO:

> **[subgenre](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/subgenre)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> A subdivision of a genre of literature, music, film, etc.
>
> ‘Some subgenres, such as the Gothic and science fiction, have until
>   now made little headway in Arabic popular culture.’
>
> **[genre](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/genre)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1** A style or category of art, music, or literature:
>   ‘the science fiction genre’

Comment: Mythology is not a genre. Stories with mythic elements can be told in multiple genres.

Answer (score 0):

## Domains

> A specified sphere of activity or knowledge:
>   ‘the country's isolation in the domain of sport’

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/domain

Beware: gods and goddesses have their own *domain*s too in which they rule; depending on the context that may confuse readers.

Answer (score -1):

Forms

Webster: :  the essential nature of a thing as distinguished from its matter:

b :  the component of a thing that determines its kind

"I am open to other forms of mythology"

Comment: This means something different — simple stories vs. complex structures, epic narratives vs allegorical parables, etc..  Different forms of mythology may be found _across_ cultures

Answer (score -1):

How about 'sources'?

> Source: A point of origin. (Merriam-Webster.)

Comment: These bodies of mythology (heh, see what I did there?) may be sources for stories today, but taken as themselves, they're not sources, they just _are_ (and in fact all have sources of their own). So this could work in some context, but I don't think makes a good choice in general.